# Code keeps giving a InputMismatchException when I type 2 words

Tags: java

```
if (userOption == 2) {
    System.out.println("You have chosen produce! Please enter (1) for organic or (0) for non-organic.");
    type = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a name for this produce.");
    name = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of calories.");
    calories = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of carbohydrates.");
    carbohydrates = sc.nextInt();

    list.add(new Produce(name, calories, carbohydrates, type));
}
```

Hello when I put a space between my words for the input for "name", it gives me an error `InputMismatchError` for the calories when Im not putting in the calories, the calories isn't even supposed to get an input until the user enters a "name". Thank you :)

Comment: you are using `sc.nextInt()` which is waiting for an int, an Integer can't contain spaces, is it that what you meant?

Comment: It is expecting an int, not words.

Comment: you expect calories to be an int and not a String

Comment: For which input you are adding space ? "calories" ? You cant add space between integers. Its expecting single integer

Comment: Please enter a name for this meat.
Beef Taco
Please enter the amount of calories.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  

It gives me an error after I type 2 words in the "name" part.

Comment: @DennisKriechel *"you are using sc.nextInt() which is waiting for an int, an Integer can't contain spaces"* Please recheck, what `nextInt` does and every upvoter of this comment should do this, as well.

Comment: @Tom I don't get your point. The javadoc for nextInt() cleary states: InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

Comment: @DennisKriechel That is right, but why do you think that `nextInt` cares about delimiters (whitespaces in this case)?

Comment: @elequang Do you know what `next` does? When you want to enter more than one word, then why do you use a single `next`?

Comment: @Tom Ah, now I get your point, instead of a space nextInt() receives "Taco" from the input "Beef Taco" which is no Integer either. Java-Doc: "A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace."

Comment: @DennisKriechel Yes, my point is that `nextInt` doesn't care about how many spaces are infront and behind a token, so *"an Integer can't contain spaces"* might be true, but not for this case, because the token won't contain any spaces.

Comment: @Tom you are right, sadly I cant change my inital comment any more :(

Answer (score 1):

Your input is "Beef Taco" which contains a white-space. The [Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) states:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

So your `sc.next();` returns "Beef" leaving "Taco" on the stream. Your next `sc.nextInt();` then returns "Taco" which is no Integer and leads into an `InputMismatchException` which [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

---

To fix it try this:

```
System.out.println("You have chosen produce! Please enter (1) for organic or (0) for non-organic.");
int type = sc.nextInt();
// Clear the input
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter a name for this produce.");
// Read in the whole next line (so nothing is left that can cause an exception)
String name = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: How would I fix this?

Comment: @elequang did that help you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to input a `String` into an `Integer`. To capture this you could change your code to something like this:

```
if (userOption == 2) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen produce! Please enter (1) for organic or (0) for non-organic.");
            try {
                type = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong format entered.");
                // ask question again or move on.
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter a name for this produce.");
            name = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the amount of calories.");
            calories = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the amount of carbohydrates.");
            carbohydrates = sc.nextInt();

        list.add(new Produce(name, calories, carbohydrates, type));
    }
```

The try/catch would capture this exception and tell the user what they have done wrong.